# Could the various anthropomorphic species (humans,devas, Rakshasas, Daityas, Danavas et al) mentioned in scripture freely interbreed?

Tags: untagged

Ravana is said to be of mixed breed - Brahmin & Rakshasa.  Kunti is a human who had children with Devas. These and many other examples suggest some interbreeding WAS possible among these species.

Do any scriptures in general talk about which species can interbreed among themselves and which species cannot?

Comment: You gave two examples, what else do you want in answer?

Comment: added clarification.